# ROS Sensors Driver Android Application Issue

Tags: ros, ubuntu, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the ROS Sensors Driver application for android devices, but have been unsuccessful in my attempts to get the app to work.  Does the android_sensors_driver work on a virtualbox version of ubuntu running  ROS?  I have followed the directions exactly how they are stated here: http://wiki.ros.org/android_sensors_driver/Tutorials/Connecting%20to%20a%20ROS%20Master but I am not able to successfully get ROS to recognize android-sensors-driver as a node.  According to the virtualbox wired connection, my IP address is 10.0.2.15.  I have tried the following

http://10.0.2.15:11311/
http://ROS:11311/                             because ROS is displayed when roscore is running
http://10.0.2.2:11311/                   because of a suggestion on an online forum

but nothing seems to work.   Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149781/ros-sensors-driver-android-application-issue/) by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-07**:
Can you include the exact commands you're running and the error output you're seeing in your question?

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-04-10**:
The terminal now recognizes the sensor drivers When I test individual node connectivity:
viki@ROS:~$ rosnode ping /android_sensors_driver_imu
rosnode: node is [/android_sensors_driver_imu]
pinging /android_sensors_driver_imu with a timeout of 3.0s
unknown network error contacting node: timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to forward port 11311 to the virtual machine.

http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

After you do that, you need to connect to your HOST machine's IP:11311.  http://HOST_IP_HERE:11311/

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-04-10**:
Thanks!  I'm now trying to test the connectivity of the nodes but I'm getting the following:
viki@ROS:~$ rosnode ping /android_sensors_driver_imu
rosnode: node is [/android_sensors_driver_imu]
pinging /android_sensors_driver_imu with a timeout of 3.0s
unknown network error contacting node: timed out

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-04-10**:
Also should my ROS_MASTER_URI also be http://HOST_IP_HERE:11311/ ?  Do I change it as well or leave it as it is?  Whenever I change that parameter to include the host ip, I get the following:  ROS_MASTER_URI [http://.......:11311/] host is not set to this machine

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2014-04-10**:
Hmmm that is tricky.

You can probably get around this by using hostnames for launching roscore and setting ROS_IP=HOST_IP.  For instance, ROS_MASTER_URI=http:://virtual-machine-name:11311/; ROS_IP=HOST_IP; roscore.

Then connect via android using MASTER_URI=http://HOST_IP:11311/

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-04-14**:
Sorry for the newb question, but when you say "virtual-machine-name" are you referring to the name given according to the initial VirtualBox start menu, which in my case would be "ROS Groovy Galapagos"?